# showing print result in a fixed or changed length table in python

Tags: python, variables, printing

I have a python code with print statments that generate this output for me

[image]

the print code I used for this output is

```
print("|----------------------------------------", end=' ')
print("|---------------------------------------|")
print("|Total number of sentences: {}".format(nos), end=' ')
print("            |Total number of sentences: {}".format(no),"          |")
print("|----------------------------------------", end=' ')
print("|---------------------------------------|")
print("|Total number of Vocabs in  file 1: {}".format(nov), end=' ')
print("   |Total number of Vocabs in  file 2: {}".format(novv)," |")
print("|----------------------------------------", end=' ')
print("|---------------------------------------|")
print("|                           The diff. in dict. is :{}".format(novcalc),"                             |")
print("|----------------------------------------", end=' ')
print("----------------------------------------|")
print("|   The number of words appearing  less than 3 times in the first file  are :{}".format(result),"  |")
print("|----------------------------------------", end=' ')
print("----------------------------------------|")
print("|   The number of words appearing  less than 3 times in the sec. file  are :{}".format(resultt),"   |")
print("|----------------------------------------", end=' ')
print("----------------------------------------|")
```

now the thing is if the numbers changed to a bigger number the table wont adjust because its a print statement for the dashes, is there a way in python to create such thing as a adjutable or fixed linghth one that may work with any output given.

Comment: This may be helpful: https://thispointer.com/python-how-to-pad-strings-with-zero-space-or-some-other-character/

Comment: yes I tried scolp library, I tried prittytable library as well, but as far as understood they don't serve my needs. @AMC

Answer (score 1):

So the problem you have is that everything is 'hard-coded'.

Once solution is to measure the size you need the table to be and then set the lines to be those lengths. For example:

```
 data = "The number of words... in the first file  are :{}".format(result)
 line = "-" * len(data) + "|"

 print(line, data, line, sep="\n")
```

However, a much more simple, and overall better solution would be to realise that over people out there have written code that solves this problem. You could try using the ["pretty table" library](https://pypi.org/project/PrettyTable/) or try playing around with a pandas dataframe and printing that.

Comment: again I dont know which print line the longest one so using your method no way to tell on which length shall I depend

Comment: The actual problem you have is that you have made life very difficult for yourself; the design of your program hasn't separated out data from operations. One thing you can do is save all the things you want to print as strings BEFORE PRINTING ANYTHING! Then you can set the size to be the max length of all your strings.

Comment: oK I made them string base like thi ```  nos = "Total number of sentences: {}".format(nos)
no =  "Total number of sentences: {}".format(no)
nov = "Total number of Vocabs in  file 1: {}".format(nov)
novv= "Total number of Vocabs in  file 2: {}".format(novv)
novcalc = "The diff. in dict. is :{}".format(novcalc)
result ="The number of words appearing  less than 3 times in the first file  are :{}".format(result)
resultt =" The number of words appearing  less than 3 times in the sec. file  are :{}".format(resultt)
line = "-" * len(resultt) + "|"  ```

Answer (score 0):

While this doesn't completely solve your problem a good place to start is

```
print("-"*80)
```

prints out 80 dashes. You can turn this 80 into a variable that can be dependent of the length of your number.

Comment: it wont solve my problem, and I  don't think my way is convenient as well, searching for better ways hopfully